# Problems viewing RGBDSLAM saved PCD files with pcd_viewer

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks

Using RGBDSLAM I have generated a few maps (small and large) and have saved them as PCD files using the GUI. However I have not been able to subsequently view them with **pcd_viewer** (installed with the ros-electric-perception-pcl-addons package) using the following command (as per http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM):

**rosrun pcl_visualization pcd_viewer -ax 0.1 test.pcd**

as I get the following error:

*> Loading test.pcd /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/bin/pcd_viewer: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/bin/pcd_viewer: undefined symbol: _ZN17pcl_visualization28PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle3NewEv*

I looks like the same issue is being experienced with the laser test group http://answers.ros.org/question/3686/point-cloud-viewer-not-working-why

**Is anyone currently able to use pcd_viewer?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12884/problems-viewing-rgbdslam-saved-pcd-files-with-pcd_viewer/) by [Mike Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/1677/mike-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-05**:
meanwhile you can post this information in ros mailing list

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-04**:
i was talking about ROS independent PCL library installed in the system. http://pointclouds.org/downloads/

**Comment by [Mike Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/1677/mike-moore/) on 2012-02-04**:
Rightio, do I need to let any team in particular know about this? Also, where do I get the standalone PCL 1.4 viewer you mentioned - its not an obvious package.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-04**:
I just checked the pcl_visualization and even i am getting the same error using it in ros. I guess this is a bug.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-04**:
I have pcl 1.4 standalone so i use pcd_viewer filename.pcd to view the cloud. I just wanted to check if the cloud is fine in your case.

**Comment by [Mike Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/1677/mike-moore/) on 2012-02-03**:
Sure thing, I'll post it shortly - but its odd that others are having the same issue with an undefined symbol - can you suggest a dependency we may be missing?

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-03**:
Could you upload the pcd file somewhere and give the link here for us to check

**Comment by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on 2012-03-26**:
Have you tried pcl/pcd_viewer instead of pcl_visualization/pcd_viewer? For me it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is because `libpcl_visualization.so` files inside `pcl_visualizations_addons/lib/` and `pcl/lib/` are conflicting. The loader is looking for the symbol inside `pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so` whereas the symbol is actually located in the other library.

I managed to workaround this problem by replacing all occurences of `pcl_visualization` with `pcl_visualization_addons` in the following three files:

- `perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/src/examples/CMakeLists.txt`
- `perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/src/tools/CMakeLists.txt`
- `perception_pcl_addons/pcl_visualization/CMakeLists.txt`

---

Originally posted by [murat](https://answers.ros.org/users/2335/murat/) with karma: 36 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2